# How to not show server side validation message if client side validation text is the same and showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have several divs with client side class validation-failure in a page like below. The text in between can change from div to div.

```
<div class="validation-failure">At least one of the above 2 fields needs to be entered</div>
```

I also have server side validation errors displayed in website as below

```
<div id="messages_product_error_view">
        <ul>
            <li>At least one of the above 2 fields needs to be entered</li>        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now I want to make sure that when client side validation is displayed and the text is same as the server side validation then only client side validation is shown. However, if client side validation error is empty div then show the server side validation. I think it can be done through jquery.. please help?

Hi

I want to capture as soon as any text shows up on a div.

This is what is happening.

As user types on an input field, client side js kicks in and shows client side js validation errors messages.

However, in some rare cases they have been able to bypass the js or the js validation is just not right. So server side validation logic have been put in place using php.

Now when types something on the input field, the client side validation kicks in.. and if user presses submit, the server side validatiojn also shows up..

I want just client side to show up .. if client side not there then show up server side....The soln you proposed works.. but in a page if user keeps on typing wrong input the client site validation message again keeps on coming with server side still there. So need to somehow detect when user types anything on input and then if client side validation shows up then dont display server side

Comment: Both the div are in html how ill u say #messages_product_error_view is server side and #validation-failure is Client-side ?

Comment: If your client-side validation has fired, why is it going to the server at all. The point of client-side is to catch these errors and not cause a post back.

Comment: #messages_product_error_view" text is server side as it is dynamically generated from MVC php in phtml side.. #validation-failure is generated by javascript..

Comment: hi @Mike, good question... The code has a bit of code debt.. so I guess all I can is don't ask...We are implementing server side validation so that the code defense is stronger.. then we will fix the code debt

Comment: I would say that you either need to fix your client-side validation so that it works correctly, or you need to remove it (comment out). If you're doing a postback no matter what, your client-side validation code is not serving any purpose.

Comment: I agree with you Mike. However, I am just a dev and business makes the final say.. I did fought somewhat in last two weeks trying to have time allocated to fix the client side validation.. However, lots of pain was thrown at me even mentioning that.. so this is something that is like a business priority

Answer (score 1):

```
var clientSide = $(".validation-failure");
var serverSide = $("#messages_product_error_view li");

if (serverSide.text() == clientSide.text()) {
    serverSide.hide();
    clientSide.show();
} else if (clientSide.text().length == 0) {
    serverSide.show();
    clientSide.hide();
}
```